# search a specific column in excel using python

Tags: python, excel, search, multiple-columns, python-3.6

I am new to coding and wanted to automate some aspects of my job for efficiency. I am writing code using python 3.6 to read an excel file (xlsx). Specifically I want it to search a specific sheet (1st sheet) and a specific column ("Current Driver") for a specific string "driver_name) which the user inputs. Sorry if my code is really bad. This is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


file_directory = input("Please enter file location (directory):  ")
file_name = input("Please enter file name:  ")
file_location = (file_directory + "\\" + file_name)
user_action = input("What you would like to do: " "Example Actions: Add 
Driver, Remove Driver, Add Vehicle, Remove Vehicle")
print (file_location)

def remove_driver(driver):
    file = pd.ExcelFile(file_location)
    sheet_1 = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name = 0)
    print(sheet_1)
    for driver in sheet_1:
        if driver in sheet_1 == True:
            print ("Found Driver")
            sheet_1.replace(driver_name, "None")
        else:
            print ("Driver not found")

if user_action == "Remove Driver" or "remove driver":
    driver_name = input("enter driver's name: ")
    remove_driver(driver_name)
```

I placed prints in the code to see what my code was doing. You can ignore those. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of what you mean with:

```
for driver in sheet_1:
    if driver in sheet_1 == True:
```

You are using the same variable for the loop as from the function.

`sheet_1` is also a panda DataFrame. The for loop iterates on the rows.

`driver_name` has not been defined (it is defined too late).

When you call `replace`, it returns a new dataframe, you may want to add `inplace` parameter to directly modify the dataframe (Otherwise it returns a copy). But anyway it does not modify the excel file.

Comment: thanks Dric for the info! In the code that confused you I tried to have it search for the driver name that the user input in sheet1 and find a match. As for the driver_name variable, I will look to define that earlier.